# Проверка checkbox "i agree" (отключен JS)

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли в браузере сделать проверку нажатия checkbox "i agree" и запретить отправку без использования JS (отключен)? Например средствами CSS скрывать кнопку Submit, но при этом чтобы форма не сабмитилась по нажатию Enter.

Надо получить рабочую форму без JS, а не отключать отправку для пользователей с отключенным JS.

```html
<form method="POST" id="target">
  <input type="text" name="phone"/> Номер телефона <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" id="agree"/> Я даю согласие на обработку данных <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="отправить"/>
</form>
```

Приведу пример кода СSS в котором мне не нравится что используются 2 кнопки сабмит (это терпимо), но то что самбит происходит по нажатию enter в поле phone не приемлемо

```html
<style>

.btn,.btn-disabled {
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}

.checkbox:checked~.btn-disabled {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:not(:checked)~.btn {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<form method="POST" id="target">
<input type="text" name="phone"/> Номер телефона <br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="agree">  Я согласен с правилами 
<button type="button" class="btn">Кнопка</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-disabled" disabled>Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Боюсь, что Enter запретить никак не получится. Я бы не заморачивался и просто проверял бы галочку на сервере, выдавая ошибку при её отсутствии

Comment: Хотя тут в ответах намекают на required, может с ним поэкспериментировать

Comment: @andreymal ну я вот не знал до недавнего времени что проверку checkbox можно сделать на CSS без JS, а вот оказалось можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока другие доводят формулировку вопроса до абсурда, оказывается, просто добавить `required` галочке более чем достаточно

```css
form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="target">
  <input type="text" name="phone"/> Номер телефона <br/>
  <input
    type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1"
    id="agree" required />
  Я даю согласие на обработку данных <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="отправить"/>
</form>
```

(Но, естественно, не забываем про дублирование проверок на сервере, потому что пользователю ничто не мешает удалить этот `required` через инструменты разработчика в браузере)

Comment: Вы оказались правы, я не до конца понял вопрос. Упустил момент какой `checkbox` проверять.

Comment: Рву волосы! Вот знал же про required, а про то что он и на чекбоксе работает не сообразил. А вот     form:invalid   для меня открытие.